# Retrieving coordinates using PyShp

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geojson, pyshp

I am working with historical wind track data, which can be found [here](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/data/tcr/index.php).

How can I use [pyshp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) to retrieve all the lat & lon along the windtrack correctly?

I used the following code found on a different question to retrieve the data from the 'lin.shp' filetype.

```
import shapefile
shape = shapefile.Reader("my_shapefile_lin.shp")
#first feature of the shapefile
feature = shape.shapeRecords()[0]
first = feature.shape.__geo_interface__  
print first # (GeoJSON format)
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((0.0, 0.0), (25.0, 10.0), (50.0, 50.0))}
```

The returned coordinates are completley off, when manually inserting the file in Google Earth the actual points and line is along the US North Atlantic Ocean,

Returned coordinates are around South Atlantic Ocean to Antarctica.

Comment: Which storm did you use ?

Comment: I am using 2020 - Hurrican Teddy on the atlantic side.

I want to retrieve all the coordinates and re-write them in a .kml file with a specified format.

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving the coordinates correctly.  Google Earth requires all data to be EPSG:4326 - WGS84 Geographic. NOAA converts this data for the KML files however the shapefiles are in an esoteric projection which QGIS identifies as "Unknown datum based upon the Authalic Sphere - Projected" for the shapefiles on that page. The map halfway down the data download page you sent is probably in that projection.

Your options are:

1. Download the KMZ, use python to unzip it, and parse the KML file inside using Python's built-in XML tools to extract the EPSG:4326 points.
2. Figure out the math to do the transformation of the points yourself to whatever projection you need to work in. Pure Python but this will be difficult.
3. Switch from using pure Python to using Fiona/Shapely to reproject the points.
4. Go one level lower from Fiona/Shapely and use the GDAL/OGR Python bindings to reproject the points.
5. Use GDAL/OGR command line tools called from Python to reproject the points.

Your project and environment restrictions plus your familiarity with these tools will determine which one of those options are best.

If you pull both the KMZ and shapefiles into QGIS or ArcMap, you will see that they overlay on top of each other in the Atlantic. Both of these tools perform "on-the-fly" reporjection if the coordinate reference system is defined.

Comment: I am restricted to using shapefiles only to retrieve coordinates. My second step involves creating a user-defined function that iterates through the coordinates and re-writes them into a .kml file with a specified format.

Am I able to do the above mentioned, not the second step using the library?

Eventually, between 2 windtracks I have a set of coordinates in the middle of the 2 and find the shortest distance between coordinate and from each windtrack - Haversine works perfectly for this.

Comment: I downloaded Hurricane Teddy and it looks like the points are correct.  You just need to write them in the KML format.  The projection probably isn't necessary. The lat/lons are also in the shape file's attributes.

Comment: Yes apologies, that was a mistake from my side, everything seems to be working fine. I went through your websites Archive to get better understanding and re-read the documentation to get a better grasp.

I have another question, the coordinates return seem to be in 1 grid (8 coordinates). Replacing 'feature' with +1 index in recalling the list gives another 8 set of coordinates(which requires re-writing commands and variables), am I able to obtain all of the coordinates in a single command line?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I was working only within the terminal before, I have to present the project soon. Will update here in few days.